# Insufficient Privileges - Salesforce

Tags: security, salesforce

I have an object which is controld by its parent (it has a Master-Detail relation).
The parents OWD is set to private.

My problem is that the user can add a parent record but when he adds a chield he gets this error message - "Insufficient Privileges - You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary"

Comment: Does the user have create privileges for the detail object?

Answer (score 0):

Does your user have the "Create" right to the Child object?

Comment: Yes, it has. I can add to tje parent but not a child record.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here may be the attributes of the master detail field on the child object.

For example, if your OWD Access to the master object is set as Read only then the master detail field on the child must also be set as read only.

You can do this by editing the field - In the Master Detail options section of the field edit page edit the "Select the minimum access level required on the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records" setting.

Hope this helps.